# Syntax error when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, into-outfile

When I run the following query

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

which is straight from the MySQL documentation, I get a syntax error. I don't have a `test_table` table and I understand that this statement won't actually work, but it doesn't seem like it should give a syntax error. If I'm getting a syntax error on something straight from the MySQL documentation, what could be going on?

This is the doc I'm looking at (5.1):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

This is my MySQL version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a Windows path for the OUTFILE by any chance? The backslash character is an escape character inside MySQL string literals.

Comment: Nope. I'm using exactly the code above. Good thought, though.

Comment: Probably due to bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58601 by default workbench slaps "Limit 1000" on the select query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me.

At first I had an `Unknown table 'test_table' in my_db` error.

After creating the table `CREATE TABLE test_table (a VARCHAR(255), b VARCHAR(255))` it just worked. No syntax error.

**Edit:**

Running the query from the official `mysql` command line client can avoid potential bugs in your GUI client and give more accurate error messages.

Comment: So if that syntax is indeed correct, maybe it's some sort of configuration issue or something.

Comment: I don't know what's going on but try running that query from the `mysql` command line client. It should work there.

Comment: You're right! It worked. More accurately, it gave more appropriate error messages. Logged in as root, it works. Logged in as the same user I was using with my IDE and I get access denied, which I know how to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to escape some of the characters depending on the language you are using.

php example:

```
$sql = "SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'"
    . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'"
    . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
    . " FROM test_table;";
```

Comment: No, I'm just pasting it directly into my IDE.